# Clicking on a list item containing sub menu in a drop down menu, closes the rest but doesn't expand the new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle, submenu

I'm creating a drop down toggling menu but I have one issue that I can't wrap my head around it. Clicking on a list item expands it's sub items, however when a list is expanded, when another one is clicked, the first one contracts as it should but the second one doesn't expand *until it's clicked again*. How can I solve this issue?

When a list is clicked a class `toggled` is added to its top parent container so I can create the conditions using jQuery - here is the code:

```
$('#main-navigation a').click(function (e) {

/* Finding the drop down list that corresponds to the current section: */
var $dropdownMenu = $(this).next();

if ($dropdownMenu.hasClass('sub-menu')) { /* Checking if drop down menu exists for this menu item */
    if ($('.nav-menu > li').hasClass('toggled')) { /* There is toggled menu */
        if (($(this).parents().hasClass('toggled')) && (!$(this).parent().hasClass('toggled'))) {
            // The curent element has only a not-direct parent with "toggled" e.g. the element is deep link!');
            $dropdownMenu.slideToggle('fast');
        } else {
            //If the element is a top link, the class is removed and the lists dissappear
            $('li.toggled').removeClass('toggled').children('ul').slideUp('fast');
        }

    } else {
        // If there isn't a toggled menu, the current menu expands and a class is added
        $dropdownMenu.slideToggle('fast').parent('.nav-menu > li').addClass('toggled');
    }

}
})
```

The whole HTML, CSS an JS code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nUrjy/

I am not even sure if this is the best way to do a menu like this one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a little change here: http://jsfiddle.net/JWMarchant/nUrjy/7/

Simplified the code to this:

```
$('#main-navigation a').click(function (e) {
   /* Finding the drop down list that corresponds to the current section: */
   var dropdownMenu = $(this).next();

   if ($(this).parent('li').children('.sub-menu').length > 0) {
      $('.sub-menu').not(dropdownMenu).not(dropdownMenu.parents()).slideUp('fast');
      $(dropdownMenu).slideToggle('fast');
   }
});
```

Comment: I also tried this code in the beginning but the problem is that it doesn't expand the submenus in Item Category 2 :(

Comment: Oh, excellent, that solves it! =] I have only one question, can it be created in such way that clicking the last link in the three doesn't slideUp the menu? @jam6549